# When trying to upload a large (100 million row) dataset, readr will not import one of the columns in my dataset

Tags: r, csv, import, timestamp, readr

I'm importing a dataset with approximately 100 million rows into RStudio using Import Dataset -> From Text (readr). The .csv has four columns, one of which is timestamp information (date and time) and the other three are numeric values. When I click Import, only three of the columns (the numeric value ones) are uploaded and my fourth column with the timestamps is not.

I suspect the problem is related to how large the dataset is because I have a smaller dataset (approx. 700,000 rows) with the same format and data types that uploads all four columns no problem. I don't know if this is relevant but the timestamp column is the first column, followed by the other three. So it should be Timestamp, X, Y, Z, but right now all that imports is X, Y, Z.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with "fread"? Is specially useful for large datasets.

```
library(data.table)
data3 <- fread("C:\\filepath\\data.csv")
```

Comment: Just tried it, still only three columns!